# Do many of the betamax voip services allow caller id spoofing?

Tags: voip, sip, caller-id, spoofing

There are many betamax voip services such as [voipgain](http://www.voipgain.com/en/index.html), [voipcheap](http://www.voipcheap.co.uk/en/index.html), [voipstunt](http://www.voipstunt.com/en/index.html) which ask you to supply a ***phone number*** and a ***destination phone number*** when making a call (as can be seen in the free trial window on their webpages-I believe them to belong to betamax). Do they allow a user to select a phone number arbitrarily for spoofing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These trunk providers can indeed send anything to the telephone network, but whether they allow you to select the number is based on their own policy.

But in the case you asked, where you provide your phone number and the destination number, they have to actually ring your phone first before they connect the destination, so this is kind of authentication.

Also, good providers also requires similar authentications if you require your number (instead of the provider's) to be used as caller id.

Comment: This is often controlled by a higher organization. In the US at least, there are FCC rules that require any phone provider to use only a number that appears on the bill to be used as the calling line ID number. Furthermore, providers are also only allowed to use the name that appears on the bill as the calling line ID name. If they wish to use something different, they have to provide legal documentation that proves they have the legal right to use that name for their caller ID.